# Vuex problems, important project, MapActions,MapGetters

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuex, vue-router

The reason why I am writing here because I just got a job as a front-end developer and on the first day they threw at me a big project and I lost, very lost, hopeless.

My job would be that I am having a home page where there is a table with some information for example date, hours, the daily wind speed, daily celsius, and under the table there would be information which can be generated from a config panel.
So basically with Vue-router am having two pages, one with the home and one with the config panel, now in the config panel I am having a form where you can write your text you want to display to the home page  and my problem is that I have no clue how to display that text from one router to another I tried to  make a method where on submitting the form  it should somehow commit that message to my Vuex state  but when I am about to write it out to the home page it is now showing,

This is what I have in my modules (vuex file) :

```js
const state = {
    message: '',

};
const getters = {
    message: (state) => {
        return state.message;
    },

};

const actions = {
    setMessage: ({
        commit,
        state
    }, newValue) => {
        commit('SET_MESSAGE', newValue);
        return state.message;
    },

};
const mutations = {
    SET_MESSAGE: (state, newValue) => {
        state.message = newValue;
        console.log(state.message);
    },

};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations,
};
```

when I am console logging the state.message the text which got submitted is there now I need to put this text to my homepage, please help me with that I know that this should be an easy one but I cannot solve it.

Comment: Hi this is actually just a metter of mapping the state to your home component. please refer https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On home page you should add

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('SET_MESSAGE');
}
```

This code will call SET_MESSAGE

```
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
        message: 'message',
    }),
}
```

After adding this part you can take message value simple call "this.message" in methods or "message" in template

Comment: Thank you so much :)    Is there anyway I can contact you   through out discord or somehow where i could ask this kind of dummy questions? vue is quite new for me.